# Is it bad practice to make all of my web pages .PHP pages?

Tags: php

Is it bad practice to make all of my web pages .PHP pages? My main reason for doing this would be to prevent myself from writing repeating code for things such as my nav bar and footer and having these in separate files so that I can 'include' them in a way similar to below.

```
<?php include('nav.php'); ?>
```

I was made aware that you can also use JavaScript to do this however my thoughts are that relying on JavaScript for something as crucial as a nav bar would be a bad idea.

Comment: Quite simply... No

Comment: I suggest you to study some template engine, like blade, smarty, twig, etc.

Comment: No -- but if you recognize that need and you're willing to go to that extent, then you might want to look at a templating system like [Twig](https://twig.symfony.com/).

Comment: Or just use plain PHP since it is its own templating engine.

Comment: Over 75% of all the websites on the entire Internet built with a server-side programming language are PHP.

Comment: There's some merit in using Javascript for simple 'includes'.  In that all you then need is simple static hosting.  As long as you provide an alternative for non JS users and robots.  Like a sitemap.  You might also want to look at static site generators.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of an opinion question than anything. I would not consider this to be bad practice as long as the following conditions are met:

1. If someone browses to https://example.com/nav.php or any similar "include only" nothing bad can happen as a side-effect. By bad I mean that if the .php expects to be included from wider context and ends up wiping the database for example. Easy way to prevent this is to declare a constant in your main "page" files and check that in the includes.
2. You find this approach easy to manage. In a larger page you might end up with a lot of files that are included from different places and expect certain global variables to be present. In these cases structuring your directories correctly and documenting the code is essential.

Happy coding!